# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, javaapns

I am using gson maven dependency and apns maven dependency `(com.notnoop.apns version 0.2.3` which is creating this error, using `version 0.1.6` is fine but some methods i want is not available here) and i want the response in json format only, converting it to `toString()` would change my whole project response

```
Root cause: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asString"])

Root cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
```